# Can Team Foundation Server integrate with an external Git server?

Tags: git, team-foundation-server

Can a Team Foundation Server (TFS) CI job be triggered by an external Git server? In other words, if we decide to set up an TFS server some time in the future for running CI workflow on Microsoft based software, is there any reason why the TFS CI workflow wouldn't integrate with a self-hosted Git product?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/overview?view=vsts

Comment: Thanks for the link. I can't seem to find any information on integrating TFS  CI jobs with an external Git server. Would you mind pointing me to the exact location for this information?